# Composable visibility not changing on State change

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have a `isLoading` state and I'm trying to show a `CircularProgressIndicator` when the value is `true`.

```
@Composable
fun ProductDetailScreen(
    viewModel: ProductDetailViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val productState = viewModel.productState.value
    LazyColumn{
        item {
            if (productState.isLoading)
                CircularProgressIndicator()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a `Resource` class for my API call results and in the repository I use this class to wrap my request result.
The problem is, although I'm returning `Resource.Loading` from the repository, the `isLoading` state is not being updated from `ViewModel` and the ProgressIndicator is not shown in my screen. What could be causing this behavior?

```
sealed class Resource<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val message: String? = null,
    val errorType: ExceptionMapper.Type? = null
) {
    class Success<T>(data: T?) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String, errorType: ExceptionMapper.Type, data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data, message, errorType)
    class Loading<T>(isLoading: Boolean = true) : Resource<T>()
}
```

**Repository**:

```
override suspend fun getProductComments(productId: Int): Resource<List<Comment>> {
        return try {
            Resource.Loading<List<Comment>>()
            delay(3000)
            Resource.Success(apiService.getComments(productId))
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            val mappedException = ExceptionMapper.map(t)
            Resource.Error(message = t.message!!, errorType = mappedException.type)
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel:**

```
@HiltViewModel
class ProductDetailViewModel @Inject constructor(
    state: SavedStateHandle,
    private val productRepository: ProductRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val passedProduct = state.get<Product>(EXTRA_KEY_DATA)
    var productId = passedProduct?.id

    var productState = mutableStateOf(ProductState())
        private set

    init {
        getProductComments()
    }
    private fun getProductComments() {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                productId?.let { pId ->
                    when (val commentResult = productRepository.getProductComments(pId)) {
                        is Resource.Success -> {
                            commentResult.data?.let { comments ->
                                productState.value =
                                    productState.value.copy(
                                        comments = comments,
                                        error = null,
                                        isLoading = false
                                    )
                            }
                        }
                        is Resource.Error -> {
                            productState.value = productState.value.copy(
                                isLoadFailed = true,
                                isLoading = false,
                                error = commentResult.message
                            )
                        }
                        is Resource.Loading -> {
                            productState.value = productState.value.copy(
                                isLoadFailed = false,
                                isLoading = true,
                                error = null
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Whats your initial Resoure State? Have you checked the observing composable that its being re-composed and the Resource state changes?

Comment: The initial state is like `isLoading: Boolean = false`. I just checked and found out only the `comments` are added to the State data class. But the `isLoading` doesn't change! Tell me If you need any code to be added to the question. @z.y

Comment: Updated the question with more code from ViewModel. @z.y

Comment: How do you initialize productState in your composable?

Comment: Added the codes to the question. @z.y

Comment: Is your ProductState initialized with isLoading = false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your'e only checking this

```
is Resource.Loading -> {
        ...
}
```

when the repository returns, at this point its useless because when the call to `getProductComments` is done, it's already `Resource.Success`.

```
 return try {
      Resource.Loading<List<Comment>>() // you'll never get this value
      delay(3000)
      Resource.Success(apiService.getComments(productId))
```

So I'd suggest to update the `ProductState` before you call the repository

```
private fun getProductComments() {

      productState.value = productState.value.copy(isLoading = true)

      viewModelScope.launch {
      ...
      ...
```

or set `isLoading` to true as its initial state.

```
data class ProductState(
     ...
     ...
     val isLoading : Boolean = true
     ...
)
```